# How can I configure a single packageRepository directory for multiple solutions?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, nuget

Given a working copy that contains multiple Visual Studio solutions in different directories, how can I configure the working copy so that restoring packages in any solution will result in the packages being downloaded to one and the same directory?

The setting in NuGet.config that controls where packages are downloaded and expanded, is called packageRepository ([reference](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuget-config-file)).

Here's the places where I added a NuGet.config file (or added the setting to an existing file) and it did not have any effect:

- the same directory as the solution file
- a parent or ancestor directory of the solution file
- the .nuget directory that is in the same directory as the solution file

I am looking at two ways of restoring packages:

1. Using Visual Studio (the magic 'restore' button in the Package Manager COnsole)
2. Using MSBuild (where .csproj files are altered to include the $(SolutionDir).nuget\nuget.targets file)

Is it possible to configure NuGet package restore (either or both methods) to download and expand packages to the same location?

Comment: Did you close and re-open the solution after adding the NuGet.Config files or changing their contents? Visual Studio will only pick up the changes after the solution is re-opened. I normally use a .nuget/NuGet.Config file in each solution directory and that works for me. Other things I have seen that cause this to fail is if the NuGet.Config file has invalid xml in it which will cause it to be ignored.

Comment: @MattWard Thanks, that helps! In the end I move the NuGet.config to the working copy root, it looks like solutions now honor the setting, in both modes (e.g. MSBuild and Package Manager Console).